# Upgrading Hazelcast from 2.5 to 3.1

Tags: hazelcast

I was using Hazelcast 2.5. Recently we noticed "APPARENT DEADLOCK" issue on our production servers. Somewhere we find that upgrading to Hazelcast 3.0 or greater can solve the problem. Now when I am trying to upgrade to 3.1, i am getting following error in ApplicationContext.xml and it is not recognizing namespace "hz" anymore.

applicationContext-hazelcast.xml contents before upgrading to 3.1 (Removed some namespaces)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
        http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-2.5.xsd">
```

applicationContext-hazelcast.xml contents after upgrading to 3.1 (Removed some namespaces)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
        http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.1.xsd">
```

Error Message:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) 
     the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'hz:hazelcast'.
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You're right looks like there's a problem downloading the 3.1 XSD. I'm getting a HTTP 403 when I try to use hazelcast-spring-3.1.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.1.xsd
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:637)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:582)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:685)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:530)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2175)
... 31 more
```

When I upgrade to using hazelcast-spring-3.2 everything works for me and I can get a Hazelcast Instance via a Spring Bean.  Could you try to upgrade to 3.2 and let me know if that works for you.  In the meantime I'm going to raise an issue in github.com/hazelcast for the 3.1 issue.